# Can anyone tell me whats wrong with my code?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm new to programming and to c++. If this sounds stupid then you know why.
I'm having problems with my code. For some reason, not all strings with 4 letters don't go to my array when I made a  function to make that happen. Plus,
strings with 6 letters also go to my array that are only supposed to store in 4 or anything that the user wants to put.

I've tried a lot that I can't even list them down.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string LetterInput, LetterLoad, input;
    string Words[] = {"camera","lotion","fire","eggs","roll"};
    string PossibleAnswers[] = {};
    int Number;
    int Size;
    bool YesorNo = false;

cout << "Lets play HANGMAN! " << endl;
Sleep(500);

cout << "Think of a word and type in the number" << endl;
cout << "of letters there are" << endl;
cin >> Size;

for (int i = 1; i <= Size; i++){
    LetterLoad += "_";
}

for (int i = 0; i <= sizeof(Words)/sizeof(string); i++){
    if (Size == Words[i].size()){
        PossibleAnswers[i] = Words[i];
    }
}

cout << PossibleAnswers[0] << endl;
cout << PossibleAnswers[1] << endl;
```

My expected results are for the array to only show `"fire","eggs","rolls"` in that order. But the actual results are, `"camera","lotion","fire","eggs"`. Lol what is the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Arrays in c++ do not expand when you attempt to access elements beyond it's end. You are simply not allowed to try to access anything beyond the end. Even if it compiles it's incorrect to do so.

Comment: whats wrong? in short: you didnt use `std::vector`

Comment: `string PossibleAnswers[] = {};` is a zero sized array and is not allowed in c++. Several compilers may allow it as an extension but it is not portable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's corrections to your code. As said in the comments the easy way to do this is to use a `std::vector` instead of arrays. Arrays should be avoided in C++ (generally speaking).

```
#include <vector>

...

vector<string> Words{"camera","lotion","fire","eggs","roll"};
vector<string> PossibleAnswers;

...

for (size_t i = 0; i < Words.size(); i++){
    if (Size == Words[i].size()){
        PossibleAnswers.push_back(Words[i]);
    }
}
```

Note the use of `push_back` to add an item to a vector. That's something you can't do with an array, since arrays are always fixed size. This was your basic mistake.

Comment: that code is broken too! `PossibleAnswers[i].push_back(...)`?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès apologies, it's fixed now

Comment: Why are arrays avoided in c++?

Comment: @JohnRamos Because to use an array with a size that you only know at runtime (i.e. a variable length array) you must allocate it on the heap, therefore you must manually take care of its lifetime. Further, you cannot change the size of the array once created, you can only create a new one instead and copy (or move) the data over. `std::vector` does all of this for you.

Comment: @JohnRamos Because vectors are easier, resulting in shorter, less buggy code. For all the reasons that Max stated (and more).

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems. Most of them are because of your old-style C++ code. Always use the newest available standard, in your case probably C++14 or even C++17.

To make it short: use `std::vector`

Always avoid working with raw arrays. Use instead the container classes of the standard library, they'll make your life easier. In this case, `std::vector` should be your choice, since it is an easy to use and dynamically allocated (resizable) array.

```
std::vector<std::string> words {"camera","lotion","fire","eggs","roll"};
std::vector<std::string> possible_answers;
```

Currently, you use the empty array PossibleAnswers which means you have no elements inside. But - you try to use these elements.
Instead, try this:

```
for(i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i)
    if(size_input == words[i].size())
        possible_answers.push_back(words[i]);
```

You have to use `#include <vector>` in order to be able to use the vector.

And I would prefer std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500)) over Sleep(500). Try to avoid platform specific functions if there is a alternative in the standard.
To be able to use this, include the header `<thread>`.